# How do you refer to languages in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, contemporary-latin

I've seen the languages' names like *lingua Latīna* and *lingua Hispānica*, but I've read that it's more common to say *Latīne* and *Hispāne*. I was wondering if someone had a list of the languages in Latin, since I haven't found in anywhere on internet.

I prefer the adverb ones (those that end in -e) but all way to say it are accepted.

Comment: Are you asking for a list of language names, or details on different ways to say a language name?

Comment: A list, if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Latin.SE! You may want to specify two or three languages whose Latin names you want to know, or ask for a method/rule to get some/most of them. Open lists are usually difficult questions to answer, and less people are willing to answer them

Comment: Also, in order to get @Draconis to know about your answer, tagging him will trigger a notification. This is not needed if the addressee is the author of the question/answer being commented

Comment: Relevant question [one](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/466/what-did-romans-call-their-language/469#469) and [two](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/21989/how-to-say-i-know-a-little-latin-in-latin/22995#22995).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The language names are adjectives in Latin.
From *Hispanicus* you get *lingua Hispanica* and the adverb *Hispanice*.
The name of the language itself is *lingua Hispanica* ("the Spanish language"), but typically the best choice for "in Spanish" is the adverb *Hispanice*.
The other forms of the adjective can come in handy, too; languages are simply described differently in Latin than in English.
What you need is a list of adjectives.

To get started, I recommend taking a look at [names of countries in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1328/79).
The list in the answer includes the adjectives, so you can easily find what it means to speak *Danice* or *Polonice*.
Of course not all country names are associated with a language and there are languages whose names are not related to a country.

Comment: The one gotcha with this approach: French in neo-Latin is Francogallice.

Comment: @NickNicholas According to the linked list France is called *Francogallia*, so the name of the language is in line with the country. But I wouldn't be surprised if it was also called *Francia*.

Comment: Francia on https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francia, but Francogallia redirects to it. Sorry, I hadn't seen Francogall- refer to the country before.