# How to say "I know a little Latin" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like to translate the following sentence into Latin:

> I know a little Latin

Here is my attempt:

> Ego parva lingva latina

I don't know if that is right. Can someone suggest a better translation?

Answer (score 7):

I'm partial to using *scire* ("to know) + *loqui* ("to speak") in the infinitive, which means more "to know how to speak" rather than "to know to speak." Here's an example from Plautus:

Plautus, *Asinaria* IV.I.792-793:

> Parasitus: Neque ullum verbum faciat perplexabile,
> neque ulla lingua **sciat loqui** nisi Attica.
>
> And she is not to use any shuffling words, nor is she **to know how to speak** in any tongue but the Attic.

You also see this construction in Aulus Gellius' famous description of Quintus [Ennius](https://ephor.us/epitome/ennius/) (*Attic Nights* 17.17):

> Quintus Ennius tria corda habere sese dicebat, quod **loqui** Graece et Osce et Latine **sciret**.
>
> Quintus Ennius used to say that he had three minds, because **he knew how to speak** Greek, Oscan, and Latin.

You don't need the *loqui* though. You could just use *scire* + the adverb of the language (which otherwise are properly adjectives). Here are some examples:

Cicero, *De Oratore* 2.59:

> ubi sunt, qui Antonium Graece negant scire?
>
> Where are they, who deny that Antonius knows Greek?

Cicero, *Ad Familiares* 9.22:

> nihil est ergo in verbo, **quoniam et ego Graece scio** et tamen tibi dico ‘bini,’ idque tu facis quasi ego Graece, non Latine, dixerim.
>
> Then there is nothing in the word, **since I know Greek**, and I still say to you ‘bini,’ and you behave as though I spoke in Greek instead of in Latin. (Translated by Shackleton Bailey)

For the last remaining part, I would use [*paulum*](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=lsn34192%2Clsn34193) (neut. acc. adverbial usage of *paulus*), like Cicero does here:

> [epistolae] me **paulum** recreant
>
> [Your letters] restore me [=my soul] **a little bit.**

Putting that all together, you get:

> **Latine paulum [loqui] scio.**

Answer (score -3):

The answer is,

**Latinam parum scio.**

latina ~ae -f, according to the Oxford Latin Dictionary, means the latin language. And also, "parum" is an adverb, means "an insufficient amount, too little, not enough", and "scio" is to know, specifically I know.

Another answer is,

**Linguam latinam parum scio.**

This one changes the way refering to the latin language. "linguam" is the accusative case in feminine gender, means "the language". "latinam " is an adjective, means "of latin". When translated back to English it basically means "I know little the language of latin."

Comment: *Cognitio* isn't a verb. If you meant to say *cognosco* instead, I would read this sentence as "I know a small woman from Latium".

Comment: Oh, yeah, scio or gnosco might work.

Comment: Re your recent edit: be careful of "calquing." Just because *latina* can refer to the "Latin language" doesn't mean that *scio latinam* is an idiomatic translation of "I know Latin." Did you see @cmw's answer, which shows that the common form is *scio latine* (with an adverb)?

Comment: Taking about idiomatic translation, the answer has such unaddressed concern. "Latine" as an adverb means "in the latin language." Since the source of usage of latine is tranlated as speak in latin, or know to speak in latin, but the required original version, and the verb used is "to know", hard to say such alternation makes it still fluent (to know in latin), or idiomatic, anyway such answer is not cited in whole piece of it.